# Bootstrap Datepicker not working on RAZOR HTML

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker

So I have a page that needs to select a date and I'm using Bootstrap's "Datepicker" to provide for this functionality. I've tried most, if not all of the questions here and they mostly seem to be syntax issues that user end up figuring out.  Here's my code:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>

<h2 style="background-color: #e57c58; color: white; display: table; width: calc(100%); height: 50px; border-bottom: 3px solid #eee; padding-left: 20px;">Select Invoice Criteria</h2>
<div style="background-color: #e57c58; width: calc(100%); height: 5px;"></div>
<br />
<div class="container-fluid">


    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InvoiceFromDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Enter Drop-off date here"})

</div>
```

This just produces a normal bootstrapped textbox, when I click on it nothing pops up.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You using `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`, not `bootstrap-datepicker.js`. Based on the current script, it would be `$('.datepicker').datetimepicker();`

Comment: Ok thanks about that, I missed that when I used Nuget for the libraries. Now I've used boot-strap-datepicker library and it still won't work. See the edited code above.

Comment: You don't appear to have included` jquery-{version}.js` (that would be obvious if you checked the browser console). And why have you included both the minified and non-minified versions of the scripts and css files?